# How to sort and create sum data points from same year from a chart using pandas? Year formats as etc. 2018,2019

Tags: python, pandas, csv, static

I am trying to sort a chart with flight accident information. So in csv file there are different airlines, year of the accident and bunch of other things. I want to add up all the incidents by year and another chart adding by each year and each airline:

First chart desirable outcome:

| year | incidents |
| --- | --- |
| 2012 | 11 |
| 2013 | 12 |

Second chart desirable outcome:

| year | incidents | Airline |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2011 | 23 | United |
| 2011 | 20 | Hawaii |
| 2011 | 30 | United |

I tried to use `dt.year` but it's not working. Because csv year is in 2018,2019 format, not in 2018-10-12. I cannot use it as date information.

Comment: What do you mean by chart?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Per year
df.value_counts('year').plot()

# Per year, for each company
df.value_counts(['year', 'Airline']).unstack('Airline').plot(kind='bar')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much for the help. It kinda work. But it turned out to have this error message ```Tight layout not applied. The bottom and top margins cannot be made large enough to accommodate all axes decorations. ```